# Laravel 5.1 form hidden _method does not work

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I'm having issues with getting a laravel app to update or delete a resource.

Here is my view.

```
@extends('admin.master')

@section('content')

    <h1>Create an Article</h1>

    <form action="/articles/{{ $article->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">    
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    @include('admin.partials.forms.article')
    <div class="row">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Update Article</button>
    </div>

</form>

@endsection
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    return "Update Article Code Here!";
}
```

All I get when I submit the form is a blank page with the url

```
app.dev/articles/1?_method=PUT&_token=LL6Z5zHNUG1dLjjH2TDpXXCWbGnfiCKTY4cuoVbm&title=Our+Upcoming+Event+Now+Updated&description=a+brief+event+description&body=Updated+Body&category=Events
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues is that while you have to have the hidden method to allow laravel to see what you're doing, you also have to have the method="POST".

```
    <form action="/articles/{{ $article->id }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```